# Sanitizing user input HTML with htmlspecialchars, nl2br, str_replace, htmlspecialchars_decode, and stripslashes

Tags: php, html, xss

I made this function

```
function echoSanitizer($var)
{
$var = htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES);
$var = nl2br($var, false);
$var = str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\\r", "\\n"), "<br>", $var);
$var = htmlspecialchars_decode($var);
return stripslashes($var);
}
```

Would it be safe from xss attacks?

- htmlspecialchars to take away html tags
- nl2br for the new lines
- str_replace to convert the \r\n to `<br>`
- htmlspecialchars_decode to convert back the original characters
- stripslashes to STRIPSLASHES

Why I need all of that? Because I want to preview what the users inputed in and I wanted a WYSIWYG thing for them to see. Some of the input came from a textarea box and I wanted the spaces to be preserved so the nl2br is needed.

Generally I'm asking about the (htmlspecialchars_decode) because its new to me. Is it safe? As a whole is the function I made safe if I use it to display user input?

(No database involved in this scenario.)

Comment: don't do it yourself, use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: @MarkoD I actually read about it (a lot of it) and that it has a good rep and all. But is it really the way to go?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also, read about experience of the person who made this website with making his own [html sanitizer](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)

Comment: Your the only one that bothered to comment so i'll go with your suggestion. Tnx @MarkoD !

Answer (score 1):

In your case `htmlspecialchars_decode()` makes the function unsafe. Users must not be allowed to insert `<` character unescaped, because that allows them to create arbitrary tags (and [filtering/blacklisting is a cat and mouse game you can't win](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)).

At very minimum `<` must be escaped as `&lt;`.

If you only allow plain text with newlines, then:

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text_with_newlines, ENT_QUOTES));
```

is safe to output in HTML (except inside `<script>` or attributes that expect JavaScript or URLs such as `onclick` and `href` (in the latter case somebody could use `javascript:…` URL)).

If you want to allow users to use HTML tags, but not exploit your page, then correct function to do this won't fit in StackOverflow post (thousands of lines long, requires full HTML parser, processing of URLs and CSS, etc.) — you'll have to use something heavy-weight like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).